# What's the meaning of QCD phase transition temperature?

Tags: temperature, standard-model, phase-transition, quantum-chromodynamics, confinement

I read about the QCD energy level in various sources, eg: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QCD_matter), and this gives a phase transition temperature of about 200 MeV, above which quark confinement breaks down and we may observe individual quarks.

If so, why couldn't we find individual quarks since I believe 200 MeV energy level is easy to achieve in accelerator nowadays.

Comment: Deconfinement doesn't mean that we can observe individual quarks. As soon as the quarks escape the region of deconfinement, or as soon as the region of deconfinement cools to below 200 MeV, the free quarks immediately hadronize.